# Pandas: Index is duplicate. How to make it unique

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 2, 4], 'animal': ['dog', 'cat', 'bear', 'mouse']})

# just rearranging the order a bit
df=df[['id', 'animal', 'name']]

  id animal Seq
  1   dog   14
  2   cat   17
  2   bear  19
  4   mouse 23
```

As you can see above the ID is not unique, I want to create a Unique ID. 
One option I was thinking was to groupby(ID) and then create a new column, where I can create a counter. And then maybe merge the counter and ID to create a unique ID.

```
  id animal     Seq Counter NewID(counter+id)
      1   dog   14   1       11
      2   cat   17   1       21
      2   bear  19   2       22
      4   mouse 23   1       41
```

I am not sure how to achieve this

Comment: Is there any criteria on the new id? If not then just use `reset_index()` to have an increment index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter and add to original `id` converted to strings by [`Series.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html):

```
df['NewID'] = df['id'].astype(str).add(df.groupby('id').cumcount().add(1).astype(str))
print (df)
   id animal NewID
0   1    dog    11
1   2    cat    21
2   2   bear    22
3   4  mouse    41
```

Comment: Thanks but I get error: TypeError: string indices must be integers?

Comment: @user1788504 - there is used `df['id'].astype(str)` ?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd 
df=pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 2, 4], 'animal': ['dog', 'cat', 'bear', 'mouse']})
df = df.assign(id=(df['animal']).astype('category').cat.codes + 1)
df
```

the Output is:

```
   id   animal
0   3   dog
1   2   cat
2   1   bear
3   4   mouse
```